# In OpenCL, does step() count as a condition?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Conditions in OpenCL can be a performance hit, since all branches will be evaluated. If I can formulate my problem using step(), will that circumvent this problem?

Comment: It surely can circunvent the problem but not fully solve it. If you count the instrctions with if/step you will see not a big difference.

Comment: All branches are only evaluated when you have divergence within a work group. If all work items go the same way then only that side is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OpenCL is only an API specification, the most general answer is: **Implementation-dependent**.

However, since this function can be (relatively) easily calculated on any ALU - usually with a single instruction - I think it is pretty safe to assume that the answer is effectively **No**, it doesn't count as a condition.

Regarding the second part of your problem, like @DarkZeros suggested, it does not fully solve it - but it is a step in the right diretion (heh heh): If you can use the result of the step() function without this use triggering a branch, then you're good.

To illustrate, suppose I want to do the following:

```
if (x < 100) {
    z = foo();
    y = a[z];
}
else {
    y = a[x];
}
```

With `step()`, I could do:

```
int s = step(100, x);
z = foo();
y = a[z * s + x * (1-s)];
```

So, no branching here - but I *always* need to call `foo()` (or inline it) - thus my benefit is limited (or no benefit at all).